# Adding X and Y labels to pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to python, its part of my course but I don't have a great understanding of all the libraries such as pandas, and mattplotlib.

I have code

```
# plot graph for counts per minute
plt.axes(frameon=0) # reduce chart junk
minute_ct.plot(kind='line', 
   rot=0, title="Summary of packet activity",  figsize=(20,10)).grid(False)
plt.show()
```

It's currently running off a series not a dataframe so I cant label the columns to get the labels as far as I'm aware, is there a way to label the axes in the plot declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
plt.xlabel('x label')
plt.ylabel('y label')
```

You can find some examples of matplotlib usage [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py).

Comment: If you are need any further help, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
plt.set_xlabel("x label")
plt.set_ylabel("y label")
```